# A scalar integral for scalar functions over a parametric scalar?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I've been thinking on this problem, and I couldn't shake the feeling there is an embarrassingly simple answer to it, but I couldn't figure it out

Consider scalar functions $\phi(X)$ with $X\in{\mathbb R}^n$. I am interested in the problem of when a scalar function $\psi(X)$ exists such that

$$ \phi(X) = \nabla \psi(X) \cdot \nabla f(X) $$

With $f(X)$ being another known scalar function.

My initial attempt was writing $\nabla f(X)$ as a tangent flow $X'$, for which one would express the above as:

$$ \nabla \psi(X) \cdot X' $$

Which seems to be just the chain rule for $D_t \psi(X(t))$. So the intuition this gives me is that $\psi(X)$ is a sort of scalar integral of $\phi(X)$ over the integral lines of $\nabla f(X)$

Is there something else I can deduce from $\psi(X)$ given the above?

Comment: I have a feeling that there should be infinitely many solutions... I'll have more time for this later.